# How to prove that sequences of stack operations are not context-free

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

By stack I mean the language of sequences it represents, say, a stack with data domains $N$ (natural number) is: $\{ \mbox{push(0)}, \mbox{push(1)}, \mbox{push(0).push(1)}, ..., \mbox{push(0).pop(0)}, ...\}$.

This language is not against **Pump lemma** of CFL, right ? But I read from some materials that this language is **NOT** context-free. So why is that ?

Comment: Where did you read that? What is the language, exactly?

Comment: @Raphael, The language is basically an infinite set of all valid sequences that can be generated from a Stack specification (i.e., LIFO). That is all the valid sequences composed of 'Pushs' and 'Pops', e.g., $\mbox{Push(1) Push(2) Pop(2) Pop(1)}$ is a valid one, while $\mbox{Push(1) Push(2) Pop(1) Pop(2)}$ is not.

Answer (score 6):

The language *is* context-free. If we replace $\mathrm{push}(k)$ by $[_k$ and $\mathrm{pop}(k)$ by $]_k$ and delete the dots, then we get exactly all prefixes of a Dyck language with $N$ different types of brackets.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't make clear of the question. Here $N$ is the infinite set of natural numbers, it's not a single number. So in such case, is stack still context-free ?

Comment: @Goon_with_X, I don't think the question is well-defined.  In computer science, languages are always subsets of $\Sigma^*$ where $\Sigma$ is finite -- in particular, without loss of generality they are subsets of $\{0,1\}^*$.  An infinite alphabet isn't allowed.

Comment: @D.W. But how about we encode the **Push, Pop** actions with letters from   $\Sigma = \{ 0, 1, \#_u, \#_o\}$.  Say, use $\#_u 1$ to encode **Push(1)**,  use $\#_o1$ to encode **Pop(1)**,  $\#_u 10$ to encode **Push(2)** and $\#_o 10$ to encode **Pop(2)**, etc.  Now we have finite alphabet and the language is set of  sequences $ L = \{ \#_u 1 \#_o 1, ... \}$ . What conclusion can we get now ?

Comment: @Gaoang.L, That's a different language.  Rather than using the comments for an extended discussion, please ask a new question with all of the details worked out, including exactly how you plan to map it to a finite alphabet.  (Or, edit the question -- although given that this question has already gotten a good answer, it might be better to ask a new question, rather than invalidating the existing good answer to this question.)  Then, show us what you tried.  Did you try to find a grammar?  What did you try and where did you get stuck?

Comment: @D.W. Good idea and thanks. I will rephrase it and ask a new one.